# Implementing floor function in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm implementing hardware in Verilog that needs round floor numbers. for example, if 7 is divided by 3 the answer is 1. Numbers can also be negative. Anyone knows how to implement the function?

```
module test(clk, a, b, c);
 
input  [4 : 0] a,b;
output [4 : 0]   c;
wire   [4 : 0]   x;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
x = a / b;
*c = floor(x);*
end
endmodule
```

Comment: [Using $floor in Verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/350878/271336)

Comment: Depends on tye way you represent operands *a* and *b*. If they represent integeres, then typically *integer* division already provides the *floor* functionality.  The issue however is in implementing of the integer devision (/) itself in a synthesizable manner. Your synthesis tool might provide some implementation. If both represent fixed/floating point, then you need to implement a synthesizable floating point processor for divisions and the *floor* operations.

Answer (score -1):

Try performing division algorithm using repeated subtraction.
Below is a pseudo code.

```
//Example :- 7/2
temp1 = 7; cntr = 'd0; temp2 = 2  //Store the number in a register and init counter
//Perform temp1-temp2 and increment cntr until temp1>=temp2
if(temp1 >= temp2)
begin
 temp1 <= temp1 - temp2;
 cntr <= cntr + 1'd1;
end

//cntr holds the quotient, which is 3 for our case.

floor_val = (temp1 == 'd0) ? cntr : cntr - 1'd1; //Final divided value
```